# What is the difference between "Of" and "Of the"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What is the difference between

> Prince **of** sea
>
> and
>
> Prince **of the** sea

Is there a difference between these "Of" and "Of the"? Or are these words in the same meaning? And which is correct?

Comment: Can you add a larger quote for each of your examples?

Comment: Sure! " Raviel, lord of phantasms"

Comment: Sometimes people say it lord of the phantasms not lord of phantasms. Is there a difference between "Of" and "Of the" in the meaning?

Comment: "Phantasms" is plural... "sea" is not. You would never say "of sea" because singular words usually need an article.

Comment: @Catija What if the noun is used attributively, "A life song"="A song of life".

Comment: @user178049 This is not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definite article conveys the sense of referring to a particular set or group.

```
King of kings
```

Means the king of all kings

```
King of the kings
```

Means king of that group of kings.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, "a Prince of sea"= "A sea prince", "A prince of the sea" = "The sea's prince". By the same token, a noun after the *of* shouldn't be plural because it's used as an adjective.

Comment: A noun isn't an adjective! Are you suggesting my examples should be King of king, which makes as much sense as Prince of sea (i.e. none) and King of the king, which does mean the king's king just as King of the kings means the kings' King.

Comment: A noun can function as an adjective in the attributive position(linguists call it a noun adjunct or attributive noun). Anyway, I don't think this post answers the question.

Comment: Yes it does, the OP asked what the difference between the two is and I answered that. Where's your answer?

Comment: @user178049 the OP isn't asking whether nouns can be used as adjectives and a noun after the word of doesn't become an adjective it is still a noun.